# Set TLSv1.2 on HttpClient using PostMethod

Tags: java, tls1.2

I need to set a TLSv1.2 connection in this code:

```
    public String login(){
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    log.trace("#LOGIN");
    log.trace("url : " +this.url_login);
    log.trace("grant_type : " +this.grant_type);
    log.trace("customer_secret : " +this.customer_secret);
    log.trace("username : " +this.username);
    log.trace("customer_key : " +this.customer_key);

    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(this.url_login);

    post.setRequestHeader("content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    NameValuePair[] data = {
            new NameValuePair("grant_type", this.grant_type),
            new NameValuePair("client_id", this.customer_key),
            new NameValuePair("client_secret", this.customer_secret),
            new NameValuePair("username", this.username),
            new NameValuePair("password", this.password+this.security_token)
    };
    post.setRequestBody(data);
    try {
        client.executeMethod(post);
        String response  = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        .........
```

How can I do this?
I saw that is possible using SSLContext but I don't want to rewrite the code (it isn't a mine project)
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your limited in what you can do if you don't want to change code.  There's a few things you can try, the easiest is to switch to Java 8 which turns on TLS1.1 and 1.2 on by default.

You can try setting a command line switch:

java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 ...

There's a few more examples [here](https://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7), but in my experience, they only work for very specific situations.

Comment: There are any others solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately no, if you can't switch to Java 8, you most likely need to turn on TLS 1.1 and 1.2 using the custom SSLContext.  I had to do something similar, because my OS Level in production couldn't support Java 8.  You do need Java 7, because that's the first version of the JVM that supported TLS 1.1 and 1.2.  I don't believe they back-ported the support to Java 6.